# Output of an expanded array returns unexpected answer

Tags: c++

I have finished writing a program that included reversing, expanding and shifting arrays using the pointer requirement asked by the professor. Everything compiles but the answer from the expand function does not return what I wish: adding 0s after the old user input array which asks for the size of the array and the numbers you wish to put into the array. I think my problem may lie from the fact that I include a pointer on something that might not have a reference in the program. Below is my code:

```
// *numPtr refers to my old user input array and int tamaño is the size of the array


void expandArray(int *numPtr, int tamaño) {

    int *nuevoArray = new int[tamaño *2];

    for (int i = 0; i<tamaño; i++) {
        nuevoArray[i] = numPtr[i];
    }
    for (int i = tamaño; i < (tamaño*2); i++) {
        nuevoArray[i] = 0;
    }
    std::cout << nuevoArray << " ";
}
```

As I said, my theory of the code not compiling the way I wish is because I use the *nuevoArray and it has no reference in my main code, but then again, I am just a beginner with C++. I was thinking of just doing a vector, but I think I would not follow the pointer requirements placed by the professor.

Comment: Do not use special characters in your c++ code. They might give you other problems. Other than that the code should work well except for the display part, cout does not know how to print arrays, it will actualy print the memory location of the array.

Comment: Thanks good sir, that was probably why I was receiving a funky number as opposed to the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @meSudaLaPolla: Please be aware that your teacher is teaching very outdated C++. This style became obsolete around the turn of the century. In this century we use `std::vector`. With that, you'd just say `std::vector<int> nuevoArray = viejoArray; nuevoArray.resize(viejoArray.size()*2, 0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the contents of nuevoarray, just use a for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (tamaño*2); i++) {
  std::cout << nuevoArray[i] << " ";
}
std::cout << "\n";
```

Also, since you are using `new[]` to create the array, you should not forget to `delete[]` it!

Comment: Thank you gsamaras! This seemed to work. Curious though, why do we delete temporary arrays that we create? To stop memory leakage?

Comment: `new` will allocate memory dynamically. That means it won't de-allocate the space allocated, unless you say so (by using `delete`). So, yes, if you don't delete that array, you will have a dangling pointer-a memory leak and you don't want that @meSudaLaPolla. ;) U r welcome! Also nice question, +1.

Comment: @meSudaLaPolla: I've edited the last line. It was right but didn't apply to your code. `new` goes with `delete` and `new[ ]` with `delete[ ]`.

Comment: @MSalters thank you very much, since I was questioning myself whether I should state that clearly, or let the general rule on the table. You answered, as a gift I will upvote an answer of yours I like.

Answer (score 0):

you can print your array by using

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < tamano * 2 ; ++i) {
 std::cout << nuevoArray[i] << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

or in c++11

```
for (auto i : nuevoArray) {
     std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
```

PS: The std::endl will return to the start of the new line and flush the cout buffer.

Comment: You have been very helpful Gabriel de Grimouard. When you say flush the cout buffer, does that mean we begin the index continuously at the 0 index?

Comment: @meSudaLaPolla no, he just means that the output buffer (the one that holds the data you want to print in the screen), will be flushed right away (in comparison to the newline I have in my answer, which will have the same effect in the screen, but it won't force the output buffer to be flushed and will rather let the system decides when it's a good time to do so). Don't use `std::endl`, unless you need to. When on **debugging** mode, **always** use `std::endl`.

Comment: @gsamaras: Debugging output can also go to ` std::cerr` which is flushed by default. Makes it easier to find those lines. You can even have a global `auto& debugOut = std::cerr` to make it really clear which statements are for debugging.

Comment: Yes, but I was talking about the case of `std::cout`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does appear to be allocating a larger array and correctly copying data from `numPtr` into the new array and also correctly filling the remainder of the new array with zeros.

You don't explicitly say what you expect this function to output, but I'm guessing you expect it to print out the contents of the new array, and that you believe there's a problem because instead of that, you're seeing it print something like "0x7fb46be05d10".

You're not correctly printing the array out. Instead you're printing the memory address of the first element out. If you want to see the contents, then you need to loop over the elements of the array and print each one out individually.

Here's a function showing one way of doing that:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

void printArray(int *arr, int n) {
  std::copy(arr, arr + n, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Now you can replace the line `std::cout << nuevoArray << " ";` in your existing code with `printArray(nuevoArray, tamaño*2);`

(Also it sounds like whoever is teaching you C++ should take a look at this presentation from the recent C++ conference, CppCon 2015: [*Stop Teaching C*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk))

Comment: Barnes53, thank you for the information and the video. Well, this class is pretty much a teach yourself class as the class is online and the teacher hardly answers questions. You are correct, I fixed the cout of the array and now it no longer prints out the funky 0x000ef etc. I appreciate your help. Now I have to look up the std::copy function so I can use it properly in the future. That's why programming is never dull! Peace.